# php in insert data to table

Tags: php, syntax-error

I started php just for 2-3 days how should i insert an variable to db and for what reason i got this error?

i think i didnt underestand strings and inserting to db completely

if you can suggest me some books its very good

Thank you for your help

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\babak\register.php on line 21
```

When running this script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>register
    </title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('babak');
?>

thanx for your registering &nbsp;<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br/>
your email is <?php echo $_POST["E-MAIL"]; ?><br/>
<?php
    $sql ="INSERT INTO users(id,pass) VALUES ($_POST['id']','$_POST['pass']')";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I smell sql injection. It stinks pretty badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(id,pass) VALUES ($_POST['id']','$_POST['pass']')";
                                                ^  ^           ^    ^
```

the indicated quotes are not permitted when you're directly inserting array values into a double-quoted string. Use either of

```
$sql = "INSERT .... '$_POST[id]', '$_POST[pass]'";
$sql = "INSERT ... '{$_POST['id']}', '{$_POST['pass']}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you embed arrays in a double-quotes string you have to use `{$foo['bar']}` or `$foo[bar]` without single quotes:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(id,pass) VALUES ('{$_POST['id']}', '{$_POST['pass']}')";
```

But as already mentioned in my comment to your question, you need to take care of SQL injection and escape untrusted input:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(id,pass) VALUES (
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass'])."')";
```

Comment: even better is to enclose em with braces: `$sql="INSERT INTO users(id,pass) VALUES ('{$_POST['id']}', '{$_POST['pass']}')";`

Comment: Please do not forget to upvote and accept the answer. And maybe have a look at PDO. It's much better than the old `mysql_*` api.

Comment: sure my friend its take 9 minutes after an answer to can accept it i have another question how i can browse my data in php my admin

Answer (score 0):

Your query (and string actually) is invalid. Also, never EVER use the user input directly as a malicious user can trivially break your script and hack into the database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(id,pass) VALUES ('$id','$pass')";
```

Where `$id` and `$pass` are escaped versions of `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['pass']` respectively.

I suggest you read some good books about PHP security.

Comment: hmm tanx my friend can u suggest me some books about security

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books - First 2 of the PHP category.